# WPF: using RichTextBox / FlowDocument in ToolTip

Tags: wpf, tooltip, richtextbox, flowdocument

I would like to use RichTextDocument / Flow document as content of tooltip to get more formatting features in tooltip. But some strange results happen:

- If use RichTextBox inside tooltip

  ```
  <Label Name="sbLabelActions" Content="{Binding ActionsCount}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StatusBarLabelWithText}" MinWidth="40" >
      <Label.ToolTip>
          <RichTextBox>
              <FlowDocument><Paragraph>Bla-bla</Paragraph></FlowDocument>
          </RichTextBox>
      </Label.ToolTip>
  </Label>
  ```

[image]

- If use Flow document directly inside tooltip

  ```
  <Label Name="sbLabelActions" Content="{Binding ActionsCount}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StatusBarLabelWithText}" MinWidth="40" >
      <Label.ToolTip>
              <FlowDocument><Paragraph>Bla-bla</Paragraph></FlowDocument>
      </Label.ToolTip>
  </Label>
  ```

[image]

Could you please suggest correct way? How to disable that BIG preview window? Maybe flow document usage is not the best way? I realize that I can just add StackPanel and fill with TextBlocks, but it's instresting now what's wrong with FlowDocument? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `DataTemplate` for [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) contains a [`FlowDocumentReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx) that is used to display the document. If you don't want to dynamically choose between [`FlowDocumentPageViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentpageviewer.aspx) and [`FlowDocumentScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx) you can use them directly.

```
<Label.ToolTip>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>Bla-bla</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>                    
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
</Label.ToolTip>
```